# Change "magento widget" name in WYSIWYG

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, widgets, magento-1.14, widget-instance

[image: I want to change this name]

In Admin (WYSIWYG) How do I change the name (through code) of my custom widget to something else than "magento widget"? Is it possible to change the icon for it as well?